# How to get the Content from Specific Field from JSONObject Data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i want to get from this JSONObject Data , the content of field "_source",

```
JSONObject jsonObj =   
{  
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "try1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "target" : {
            "br_id" : 0,
            "wo_id" : 2,
            "process" : [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "explanation" : {
            "an_id" : 1311,
            "pa_name" : "micha"      
          },
          "text" : "hello world"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

the Result should be like bellow ,

```
String result = 
{      
          "target" : {
            "br_id" : 0,
            "wo_id" : 2,
            "process" : [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "explanation" : {
            "an_id" : 1311,
            "pa_name" : "micha"      
          },
          "text" : "hello world"
        }
```

I tried this , but it always could not recognize the "_source" field,

```
            JSONObject main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("hits");
            JSONObject content = main.getJSONObject("_source");
            JSONObject field = content.getJSONObject("target");
```

```
JSONObject["_source"] not found
JSONObject["target"] not found
```

Please any suggestion or Advices, so i can get the Content from "_source" as Result? 
thx.

Answer (score 1):

`_source` is inside of JSONArray `hits`, so first get the `JSONArray`

```
 JSONArray main = jsonObj.getJSONArray("hits");
```

And then get the first `JSONObject` from array

```
JSONObject obj = main.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject source = obj.getJSONObject("_source");  //now get the _source
```